# adding_condition_to_sql_query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, conditional-formatting, having-clause

I have a table containing bookings rows, and teachers making these bookings (a teacher can have many bookings).

bookings can be one of two types :

***type 1 :those with (only_payment = true OR from_lesson_id IS NOT NULL)***

***type 2 : and those with (only_payment = false AND from_lesson_id IS NULL)***

only_payment is boolean, from_lesson_id can be null or not null

I executed this query and it works correctly :

```
SELECT

bookings.id as booking, 
bookings.from_lesson_id,
bookings.only_payment,
bookings.teacher_id

FROM bookings
```

I want to add a condition, to keep only teachers who have at least one booking from each type.
I tried with having condition, group by (bookings.teachers_id) but it is still not working.
How can I do please ?

sample data :

booking | teacher_id | only_payment | from_lesson_id

333,         01,          true,            null

334,         01,          true,           not null

335,         01,          false,           null

336,         02,          false,           null

337,         02,          false,           null

Here, teacher 01 has two type I bookings and one type 2 bookings, while teacher 02 has two type 2 bookings, and no type 1 bookings.

So, the desired output would be to keep only teacher 01 bookings :

booking | teacher_id | only_payment | from_lesson_id

333,         01,          true,            null

334,         01,          true,           not null

335,         01,          false,           null

Comment: Your question is really hard to follow.  I see no columns called `only.payment` or `from_lesson_id`.  I am guessing that you could simplify the logic by removing extraneous tables, clearly explain the logic, and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I simplified it, I guess it's readable now !

Comment: Use two separate EXISTS() terms, one for each type.